# Phpdocx word documents are corrupt when adding images

Tags: php, docx, phpdocx

I'm using Phpdocx 2.5 to convert html to docx. I'm using the embedHTML method with 'downloadImages' parameter set to true; 
When the html doesn't contain any images, document is generated just fine. When images are added, the resulting document seems to be corrupt. The details of the errors show a standard "File is corrupt and cannot be opened" message. However, Word also displays a "Do you want to recover the content" message which if clicked, displays the content (with images) which look just fine. 
Basically the content seems to be rendered correctly but there is an issue somewhere that causes Word to see the document as corrupted. Anyone had this problem or can you give me any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372094/phpdocx-add-image-makes-docx-corrupt/35431687#35431687 ... might be the same problem though this was created long time ago on another version...